# After login using java code to website server sends response code 500

Tags: java, web-services

I want to make java program to download a file from website, but i'm stuck in following situation. When I run the following code logging to page gets done successfully, but after it is done, when I send request for the next page, it shows response code 500.

```
public class Ss2mydb
{
    private List<String> cookies;
    private HttpURLConnection conn;

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String indexPage = "http://10.100.100.142/index.asp";
        String validatePage = "http://10.100.100.142/validate.asp";
        String ccmenuPage = "http://10.100.100.142/callcentre/ccmenu.asp";
    String reportPage = "http://10.100.100.142/topmgmt/reports/PROJECTVIJAY/get_download_cafs.asp";
        String reportPageDownload = "http://10.100.100.142/topmgmt/reports/PROJECTVIJAY/get_download_cafs.asp?view=N";

    Ss2mydb http = new Ss2mydb();

    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
    String page = http.GetPageContent(indexPage);
    String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username", "password");


    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
    // authentication
    http.sendPost(validatePage, postParams);
//        System.exit(0);

    // 3. success then go to gmail.
    http.GetPageContent2(ccmenuPage);
        String result = http.GetPageContent2(reportPage);
    System.out.println(result);
    }

    private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "10.100.100.142");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            System.out.println(" sendPost : "+cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://10.100.100.142/index.asp");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

//        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    // System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

    private String GetPageContent2(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        System.out.println(" L : "+cookies);
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                    System.out.println(" GetPageContent : "+cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
//        System.out.println(" Get : "+conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));
//  setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    return response.toString();

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        System.out.println(" L : "+cookies);
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                    System.out.println(" GetPageContent : "+cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
        System.out.println(" Get : "+conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));
    setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("right");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("USERname"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("password"))
            value = password;
                if(!key.equals(""))
                    paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`500` means "Internal server error" (see [HTTP codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and their meaning).

It does mean that the request you sent was understood and was valid HTTP, but either there is an internal, unrelated issue, or the request you send is missing some parameter or is sending some incorrect value, and that omission/mistake causes the server logic to crash (either because it fails a validation of the request content or in a deeper, uncontrolled way).

The only way to get more specific info would be seeing the server logs (and that if the developer was careful checking parameters and logging info).

Your best option is to analize the traffic between the web browser and the server using some tool like wireshark, and then analize the traffic between your client and the server and try to spot the differences.